# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with USING clause giving errors

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

All,

I am very new to stored procedures in general but I am struggling especially with those in Oracle. I have created a very simple example of what I am trying to accomplish and I am still getting the same error with this simplified version.

The example stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ashish_test
AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
BEGIN
     DECLARE
          v_tab     VARCHAR2(50);
          v_strSQL  VARCHAR2(50);
     BEGIN
          v_strSQL := 'SELECT * FROM :1';
          v_tab    := 'ex.emp';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_strSQL USING v_tab;
     END;
END;
```

When I call the above stored procedure using `CALL ashish_test()`, I get :

[Error Message http://web1.twitpic.com/img/12831839-06a3ea536df5d5a0a839eb83d9e59d25.4a3936b8-scaled.jpg](http://web1.twitpic.com/img/12831839-06a3ea536df5d5a0a839eb83d9e59d25.4a3936b8-scaled.jpg)

Based on [this article](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/support/oracle/doc/10.2/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm) (Look for Example 7-1), `USING` keyword should replace the numbered placeholder (`:1`) within `v_strSQL` with the value stored in `v_tab`. However, I keep getting invalid table error. I am guessing it's because `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is unable to replace the placeholder with the value for some reason but I am not sure why that is. Does anyone know if I am doing something stupid here?

I am running this on Oracle 10g database & using PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Related: [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489002/1461424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USING clause is only for bind variables (i.e. where you would use column names in a select statement), not table names. Typical usage would look like this:

```
Select col1 from table1 where col2 = :a
```

If you want to use variable table names use something like this:

```
         v_tab    := 'ex.emp';
         v_strSQL := 'SELECT * FROM ' || v_tab;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_strSQL;
```

Comment: Thanks Diederik! It's weird that Oracle's execution hierarchy makes it impossible to dynamically change table names & column names using the placeholders. I went with your suggestion for a workaround.

Comment: A bind variable can only hold a single atomic value - it cannot refer to a result set. A FROM clause can only refer to result sets (e.g. you can't "SELECT * FROM 'abc'") - so a bind variable just doesn't make sense in that context. This "workaround" is exactly the way you can dynamically alter the result set that the query acts on.